# Non Obvious Reasons a Power Meter would be in a Home Electrical Panel?

Tags: electrical-panel

Last year I purchased a house that was built in 2012.  I began looking into installing a power meter for the whole house (such as a Sense or Emporia Vue), however I discovered today there's already a WattNode Modbus wnc-3y-208-mb installed in the electrical panel.  The manufacture date is in 2012, so I suspect it was installed when the place was built.  I have no idea what it would be for, though.

There's a serial cable attached to it, which exits the top of the panel.  I'm not able to see where it goes after that, and the comm status LED doesn't blink (at least not for as long as I was looking).  The only other interesting things I can think of are that the house was built with solar, and it's all electrical.  No gas whatsoever.

Is anyone aware of why a power meter would be installed when the house was built?

Comment: Maybe to track net usage internally to compare against utility bills?

Comment: Well the serial port leaving the panel is illegal unless it goes through a conduit into another enclosure.  Why did they use a 3-phase sensor?  What wires is it clamping? I would review your solar contract CAREFULLY - you see the "get solar with no cost to you" ads... under many of those contracts, the panels on your roof do not belong to you, or the power generated does not belong to you.  That said, having two CTs on the same wire is not a problem.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact That seems to be the obvious answer, but I don't know what the device connects to and who would be monitoring.  It could be leftover from a previous owner.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica As far as I can tell, it leaves through a conduit, though I can't see where it goes after that.  Not sure on the model choice, though reading the spec sheet, it can (and presumably is) configured to monitor power use on two single-phase incoming service lines.  Those are the only two lines clamped.  On solar, AFAIK, I don't have a contract and do own the panels outright.

Comment: Why are you so surprised that a power meter is already installed since you are considering doing the same?

Comment: Any idea where that conduit is going?  Another thought is load-shed equipment to deal with an oversubscribed panel, i.e. auto-disconnects water heater or A/C if Utility draw is approaching limit.  Or a favorable electric rate plan which does something similar.

Comment: @Barry I'm not trying to work through my surprise, more so trying to understand why it might be there.  Knowing whether I must keep it functional as is, or if I can repurpose it for my needs, dictates my next steps.

Thanks Harper, that makes sense.  It sounds like my answer lies at the end of that serial cable.

Comment: Can you get in touch with the previous owner?